# Ubuntu does wake up from suspend for no particular reason

Tags: usb, suspend, wakeup

I'm running this version

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

```
Linux yoga-2 5.18.0-051800-generic #202205222030 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun May 22 20:33:46 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

on Lenovo yoga and usc-c dock with multiple monitors, keyboard, mouse and some other peripherals attached. Everything works very well, except if I suspend it, I find it awake after some time. I read about disabling wakeups and a disabled them all after boot.

```
cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
GP17      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:08.1
XHC0      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:03:00.3
XHC1      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:03:00.4
```

Anyway the notebook wakes up. It sounds crazy but feels like it reacts to sound or motion (in front of its camera).

So I would like to know how to find out what wakes up the computer and how to disable everything (including crontab jobs, schedules, monitors, all usb devices...) except power button from waking it up.

Comment: Some of your pasted details do not match a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system so providing details on what you've done maybe helpful.   Does it work on the unmodified system?

Comment: I does not work on unmodified system either, I'm using latest kernel installed by mainline. That's all modifications.

Comment: Problem still persist in Ubuntu 23.04, sometimes it feels like its being waked up by sound.

Comment: Your details show you're not using a Ubuntu kernel, what OS/release are you using? and why the non-Ubuntu (or *older testing*) kernel?